# How to enable CSP(Content Security Policy) in Jquery 3.4.1 & Jquery-ui 1.12.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, content-security-policy

I'm currently using **jQuery 3.4.1** and **jQuery-UI 1.12.1** (for autocomplete) on my website.  I'm also using `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` which I don't want to use.

My `<meta/>` tag:

```
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https: cdnjs.cloudflare.com code.highcharts.com stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com cdn.jsdelivr.net code.jquery.com 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' news.google.com; worker-src 'self'; manifest-src 'self';"
>
```

Expanded, that `content` is:

```
script-src
    'self'
    'unsafe-eval' 
    https: 
    cdnjs.cloudflare.com 
    code.highcharts.com 
    stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com 
    cdn.jsdelivr.net 
    code.jquery.com
    'unsafe-inline'; 

connect-src
    'self'
    news.google.com;

worker-src
    'self';

manifest-src
    'self';
```

Whenever the AJAX call happens in jQuery-UI autocomplete, it throws an error saying it violates CSP policy.

What do I need to do to properly enable CSP on my website with jQuery?  I don't want to use `unsafe-eval` and `unsafe-inline` on my website.

Console Error:
[image: Console error image]

Comment: Pretty sure this would come down to ***server*** configuration, which you have not told us about.  What is serving your content?

Comment: Actually, I'm not configured CSP in my webserver. I'm using **meta tag for CSP** in my HTML file. As you asked apache is serving my contents.

Comment: Then add the meta tag here as an edit.

Comment: I have added. please check it.

Comment: question is correct but no one provided the useful answer yet.  Can anyone please tell how to use "nonce" attribute with example to make jquery.js work?

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever the AJAX call happens in jQuery-UI autocomplete, it throws an
> error saying it violates CSP policy.

1. Show me the text of this CSP error and I'll say you what to do (Chrome console is prefer).
2. As can be seen from CSS for jQuery-UI 1.12.1 you need to have `img-src data:` in your policy.
3. As can be seen from the script 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js - it does not use unsafe eval calls. Maybe you use those in your scripts. Remove 'unsafe-eval' from the script-src and check errors raised in the console.
   If there is not messages like `Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because unsafe-eval is not an allowed` or `the page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval` - you do not need to have 'unsafe-eval' in the script-src.

   .

The best practice is to forget about insecure HTTP: and use HTTPS:. There were cases when Internet providers (in the RU-segment of the Internet) interfered with the client's traffic and injects ads into jquery lib. So:

- The rule `connect-src 'self' news.google.com;` should be `connect-src 'self' https://news.google.com;` since news.google.com always retirects to HTTPS:. All $ajax-request to news.google.com should use the https:// scheme too.
- the same is with cdn.jsdelivr.net, it always redirects to HTTPS:
  Therefore safe rules should be:

  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://code.highcharts.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://code.jquery.com

and all call the scripts should be done with HTTPS: `<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js'...`

When you specify just scheme-source `https:` in the script-src - it leads to zero-protection since any sources will be allowed via https:.

This additionally helps to avoid problems of mixed content blocking.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3541
I think the issue is with jQuery itself. If you are able to resolve, can you post your answer