# jQuery 3.5.1 and CSP script-src-elem

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, content-security-policy, browser-security

I recently upgraded jQuery from 2.1.1 to 3.5.1 and I started seeing this CSP violation in Chrome browser's console

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'nonce-7xyNokwFS08H1wnqtUmzycmiRKTgUZJQZJUN34B0v8A=' 'unsafe-eval'".
> Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-+oZkjQp5ZgVWtUq2rV5UqKJhNxGno8jem/DRZmR+mcI='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
>
> b @ jquery.min.js:2

However the posted CSP report shows

```
"csp-report": {
    "document-uri": "https://subdomain.mydomain.com/docs/s",
    "referrer": "https://subdomain.mydomain.com/",
    "violated-directive": "script-src-elem",
    "effective-directive": "script-src-elem",
    "original-policy": "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-7xyNokwFS08H1wnqtUmzycmiRKTgUZJQZJUN34B0v8A=' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; child-src 'self'; report-uri /csp/report;",
    "disposition": "enforce",
    "blocked-uri": "inline",
    "line-number": 2,
    "column-number": 839,
    "source-file": "https://subdomain.mydomain.com/lib/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js",
    "status-code": 0,
    "script-sample": ""
  }
```

So the violated directive is `script-src-elem` not `script-src` as browser's console log shows.

I understand that `script-src-elem` is added in CSP 3 and If this directive is absent, the user agent will look for the `script-src` directive, and if both of them are absent, fallback to `default-src` directive.

If I add `script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` and keep `script-src` as it is with nonce, then I don't see any violations.

```
default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-xxxxxxxx' 'unsafe-eval';script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; .......
```

I am using Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 that supports CSP 3, My question is what happens when user agent is not supporting CSP 3? In that case will it fallback to `script-src` and then throws error because I don't have `unsafe-inline` for `script-src`

Answer (score 2):

> I recently upgraded jQuery from 2.1.1 to 3.5.1 and I started seeing this CSP violation in Chrome browser's console

jQuery 2.x [uses `'unsafe-eval'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410153/csp-does-browser-check-if-the-nonce-value-in-header-matches-with-the-nonce-valu/67411354#67411354) to execute all scripts when `use strict` is omitted. This technique unintentionally does bypass the `'nonce-value'`.
jQuery 3.x doesn't do that, therefore:

- you do not need to have `'unsafe-eval'`unless you do not use eval-expressions on your own.
- you have to use `'nonce-value'` to allow inline scripts. You [gave a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081027/how-to-enable-cspcontent-security-policy-in-jquery-3-4-1-jquery-ui-1-12-1/64092976?noredirect=1#comment119092859_64092976) that jQuery 3.x had an issue with `'nonce-value'`, and it [was fixed](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3541) since JQuery 3.1.1.

> My question is what happens when user agent is not supporting CSP 3? In that case will it fallback to `script-src` and then throws error because I don't have `unsafe-inline` for `script-src`.

The `script-src-elem` is supported by Chrome only. Other browsers support 'script-src' only.
So Chrome browser will use the policy:

- `script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` for `<script>` and `<script src=>` tags
- `script-src 'self' 'nonce-xxxxxxxx' 'unsafe-eval'` for inline event handlers and javascript-navigation (since `script-src-attr` is omitted).

The Firefox/Edge/Safari will use the policy: `script-src 'self' 'nonce-xxxxxxxx' 'unsafe-eval'`.

Comment: Thanks. I think i can decide if I need to add `unsafe-inline`  This was my original issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377168/jquery-3-5-1-and-refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-it-violates-the-follow/67423065#67423065